# Why reverse proxies when HA & LB are possessed by Tomcat & apache?

Tags: load-balancing, reverse-proxy, high-availability, apache-2.2, tomcat6

Anybody has any strong reason why HeartBeat, HAProxy, NGINX or any other reverse proxies needed for apache tomcat web application when we can have HA and LB with Tomcat supported Clustering with Apache mod_jk setup?. Anybody please...?

Any other issues with these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because a package is capable of something doesn't make it the best choice for every scenario. Just because Apache can serve files and maintain HA doesn't mean that you can't do better. A reverse proxy might use less memory, less CPU, decrease latency, or all of the above.

Answer (score 1):

Because different people like to implement things differently.  After all, `mod_jk` is a reverse proxy itself.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I always confusing if there are many drawbacks only with apache & tomcat.

Comment: And I'm unable to decide myself if it could be good for production.

Comment: Don't try to decide beforehand; just create a test environment and see it for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

A benefit of NGNIX as a reverse proxy is that it can support tens of thousands of HTTP connections in keepalive state, thus reducing end-user latency for subsequent requests. Apache is not nearly as good at this. This is especially important when using SSL, as it introduces additional round trips for connection setup.

Comment: Yes, I heard few issues with SSL. Does nginx support tomcat SSL?. I am thinking whether all the feature supported by apache are also found in  nginx. If so if I've to switch from apache, I should accustom to nginx first and I don't know how long does it take.

Comment: There is no such thing as "tomcat SSL".

Comment: I mean to say I can configure ssl from tomcat side instead apache